# remove entry from javascript array object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two object array in Js

```
a = [{"photoId":"1","albumId":"121"},{"photoId":"2","albumId":"131"},{"photoId":"3","albumId":"131"}] ;
b = [{"photoId":"2","albumId":"131"}];
```

I want to remove b object array entry from the a object array..so the output should be

```
c = [{"photoId":"1","albumId":"121"},{"photoId":"3","albumId":"131"}];
```

its easy to achieve in case of array but how to do the same for array object..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an object array is more difficult, but is actually the same as a 'normal array'. Just check on its content. You should loop trough the array to check if the objects are the same. Then use the Array.slice() like this:

```
for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) //always use a reversed loop if you're going to remove something from a loop
{
  if (a[i].photoId == b[0].photoId &&
      a[i].albumId == b[0].albumId) // if the content is the same
  {
     a.splice(i, 1); // remove the item from 'a'
  }
}
```

BTW the delete-statement makes the item in the array empty, splice removes it completely, so the length of the array becomes smaller.

Note; If you are dealing with references of the same object, you could use this condition:

```
if (a[i] == b[0])
```

Ofcourse, if there are more items in 'b', you'll have too build a double loop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the del keyword:

```
delete arr["key"];
```

Comment: Do you mean the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete) keyword? Anyway, that doesn't work on arrays, you'll just create an undefined entry. By the way, array keys are numeric, so `"key"` is not a valid one.

Comment: @phihag, it's not an undefined entry, it just doesn't alter `.length`, but it ***will*** delete the element. Try: `t=[1];delete t[0];0 in t;` is `false`.