# remove object from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with the following structure :

```
var y = [{id:12,count:10}, {id:23,count:89}, {id:21,count:100},]
```

How can I remove element with id:23 ?

I am not willing to use to create a prototype method on the array Array.prototype.remove

Any pointers appreciated

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891329/remove-entry-from-javascript-array-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i in y) {
    if (y[i].id == 23) {
       y.splice(i, 1);
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's possible for there to be two elements with the matching id then this could fail (if they dups are in sequence), and if there is only one then there should be a `break` inside the if block.

Comment: its pretty bad to use a `for in` to iterate over an array. You might end up iterating methods/functions or propertys on the `Array` aswell. Better use a standard `for` loop.

Comment: In all major browsers variable i will never have property name of Array object.

Comment: @DenisErmolin: on what grounds are you making that claim?

Comment: Very good question. That is just wrong.. of course **ANY** browser will list the object properties aswell. Easy example: `var foo = [1,2,3]; foo.IAMBOSSBITCH = true;` loop over that...

Comment: Sure it will but it will not iterate through standard properties. This approach is not bad for me because i never modify standard objects. Sure if you modifying them then use for(;;) loop

Comment: beyond that, `for in` is much more slow than `for` or `while` :p http://jsperf.com/fiosdfhsoudfhodsf

Answer (score 5):

ES5 code:

```
y = y.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.id !== 23;
});
```

<sup>ES5 is widely supported by all major browsers. Still, you might want to include on of the several Shims to backup old'ish browsers</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Denis Ermolin's answer is an option, though a few problems might occur, here's what I suggest:

```
for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
{
    if (y[i].hasOwnProperty('id') && y[i].id === 23)
    {
        delete(y[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

When using arrays, it's always better to avoid the `for - in` loop, as this will loop through the `Array.prototype`, so `i` might suddenly contain `length`, not an index number.

When you're dealing with objects, the `for in` loop is a great thing, but again: it loops through the prototypes, that's why you're better off using the `hasOwnProperty` method.

The rest is pretty strait forward, I think... good luck